# Allocate specific storage space to MariaDB users

Tags: mariadb

I am using an Amazon EC2 instance and a MariaDB database.

Suppose that I have 20GB database storage and 10 user accounts. I want each account to have 2GB database storage.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any builtin way to monitor or report disk usage by user.

If you limit each user to one database:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON user1_db TO user1@'...' ...;
```

and periodically run a query like

```
SELECT table_schema AS db_name,
       SUM(data_length+index_length) / 1073741824 DB_Gigabyte
    FROM information_schema.tables
    GROUP BY table_schema;
```

to get a list of how many GB is in each database.  From there, it is up to you to deal with any over-eating users.

Caution:  Because of temp tables, free space, etc., it is quite possible for a user to temporarily exceed the limit.  Also, there are cases where inserting one small row will grow the allocation by a megabyte or more.  So, be lenient, else both you and the user will be puzzled at what is going on.

Be sure to have `innodb_file_per_table = ON` so that you can more easily deal with bloated users.